# Find objects in list that match elements in array

Tags: c#, linq

Starter code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lJhMyo

```
    string[] names = { "Burke", "Laptop", "Computer", 
                       "Mobile", "Ahemed", "Sania", 
                       "Kungada", "David","United","Sinshia" };

     var empList =  new List<Employee> {
         new Employee {Name = "Burke", ID = "IHED123"},
         new Employee {Name = "David", ID = "QIUHD454"},
         new Employee {Name = "Batman", ID = "OIWQE565"},
     };
```

How do I construct a linq query (method syntax) that gets all Employee objects where employee name is in the "names" array?

If there is a string in "names" that is not in empList, throw exception.

**EDIT:** What if empList is large and I want case-insensitive match for Name?

Answer (score 5):

You can use .Contains. ie:

```
var result = empList.Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name));
```

You can check if there is a missing name:

```
bool noneMissing = !names.Any(n => empList.Any(x => x.Name == n));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I just edited the original post with this: What if empList is large and I want case-insensitive match for Name?

What would be a more performant solution?

Comment: @JamesBurani, Linq converts Contains to an in query where there is a parameters count limit. If you are seeking for a performant search then it depends on your backend. For example for SQL Server, you would want to use a CLR UDF or something like Jeff Moden's 8K splitter function. Or alternatively, using SQL BulkCopy, you could send the names to a temporary table and do a server side join (Bulk copy is also available in some other backends). Linq is not really built for speed.

Answer (score 2):

`.Contains`  Tests if an array or list contains the item:

```
var Searched = emptList.Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name));
```

If `Searched.Length == 0`, so no Items

If you want performance use `for loop` (nothing is more performant) and for case insensitive use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

```
List<string> Searched = new List<string>;
for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    if(emptList.contains(name[i], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        Searched.Add(name[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I just edited the original post with this: What if empList is large and I want case-insensitive match for Name?

What would be a more performant solution?

Comment: If you want the more performant soltuion, forget Linq and use For Loop, its the most efficient. You could replace Array to Hashet to gain again, but be sure string is uniq

Answer (score 1):

For large lists and case-insensitive comparison you can use `HashSet` with provided `IEqualityComparer<string>` :

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(names, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
empList.Where(e => hashSet.Contains(e.Name));
```

And possibly moving from LINQ to `for` loop.